# Clarification on Dynamic Sender Profile AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like some clarification on the dynamic sender profile AMPscript. When using this in the email:

```
%%[ VAR @fromName 
SET @fromName = Lookup("MySendProfilesDE","FROM_NAME", "SendProfileField", SENDABLE_DE_FIELD_TO_DRIVE_PROFILE) 
IF EMPTY (@fromName) THEN 
SET @fromName = 'MyDefaultFromName' 
ENDIF ]%% 
%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

What does "SENDABLE_DE_FIELD_TO_DRIVE_PROFILE) mean? What should that be referencing?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the 'Where clause' value you are looking up - same as "SendProfileField" is the 'Where clause' name.

For instance:

From Name is in a DE (let's call it 'FROMNAME_DE') matched on Subscriberkey of your subscriber (as primary key).

`Subscriberkey  |  FROM_NAME`

Then in the Dynamic Sender Profile, you would need to do a lookup to the FROMNAME_DE using your Subscriberkey as the 'WHERE' clause of the lookup.

e.g.

`SET @fromName = Lookup("FROMNAME_DE", "FROM_NAME", "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey)`

Comment: If I'm looking up from a separate SenderProfileDE than my sending DE, would I still be using this method or is this assuming one DE being used?

Comment: The lookup should only be used when the info is not in the sending DE. Otherwise you can use AttributeValue() or the personalization string to fill it.